# Segmentation fault error as the reader tries to read from the shared memory

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying to understand the System V shared memory APIs. I created a small program where one writes into the shared memory and another reads from the shared memory. But for some reason, I am getting an error :

```
segmentation fault: 11
```

as I try to read from the shared memory. I could not find the reason for it.

Here is what I have done:

The following program writes into the shared memory.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/shm.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct shm_seg {
        char *buf;
    };

    int main() {
        int shmid = shmget(1, sizeof(struct shm_seg), IPC_CREAT | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP);

        if(shmid == -1) {
            printf("Failed to fetch the shared memory id");
            exit(-1);
        }

        struct shm_seg *shm_segp = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

        if(shm_segp == (void*)-1) {
            printf("Failed to attach shared memory to the shared memory id");
            exit(-1);
        }

        while (1) {
            shm_segp->buf = "hello";
        }

        if(shmdt(shm_segp) == -1) {
            printf("Failed to detach the shared memory");
            exit(-1);
        }

        if(shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, 0) == -1) {
            printf("Failed to delete a shared memory object");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

and the following code attempts to read from the shared memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct shm_seg {
    char *buf;
};

int main() {
    int shmid = shmget(1, 0, 0);

    if(shmid == -1) {
        printf("Failed to fetch the shared memory id");
        exit(-1);
    }

    struct shm_seg *shm_segp = shmat(shmid, NULL, SHM_RDONLY);

    if(shm_segp == (void*)-1) {
        printf("Failed to attach shared memory to the shared memory id");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while(i < 100 ) {
        printf("%s\n",shm_segp->buf);
        i++;
    }


    if(shmdt(shm_segp) == -1) {
        printf("Failed to detach the shared memory");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

The above reader program results in a `Segmentation fault: 11` error. What could be the reason for this? What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try this: struct `struct shm_seg shm_segp;` `shm_segp->buf = shmat(shmid, NULL, SHM_RDONLY);` Actually IMO there is no reason for having the struct at all.

Comment: Have you run the program in a debugger to see where the segfault happens?

Comment: @at77 It occurs as soon as I start the program.

Comment: Are you sure it occurs on this line: `int shmid = shmget(1, 0, 0)`?

Comment: @at77 I tried adding a `printf` before `shmget` it does not print that too. Not sure why this happens.

Comment: You must add a newline character `\n` to the printf so that the buffer gets flushed and actually something gets printed to screen.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: @at77 Editing my previous comment. It fails at `printf("%s\n", shm_segp->buf);` inside the while loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209250/discussion-between-amanda-and-at77).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        shm_segp->buf = "hello";
```

That code makes no sense. This puts a pointer in shared memory.

Your code passes a pointer to a string constant from one program to the other. Then it dereferences that pointer in the other program. But what sense does that make? It's a pointer into the other program's memory space that means nothing to a different program.

If you want to pass data from one program to another, you need to actually put the data you want to pass in shared memory. Putting a pointer to it in shared memory won't do any good if the data itself isn't in shared memory!

Comment: Even if the data were in shared memory, a pointer would still be useless to a different program unless it mapped the shared memory into the same virtual address range

Comment: Could you show an example of passing a string with `struct`?

Comment: Visualization why it doesn't work: https://imgur.com/a/1nItu8c

Comment: @Amanda Using shared memory correctly is very non-trivial. You need to arrange synchronization somehow to ensure the reader doesn't try to read the shared memory until after the writer is done writing into it. But one start would be to put a `char[64]` in shared memory instead of a `char*`, and copy the string into shared memory.